# Where can I find ratings of anime OPs and EDs?

Tags: resources

I'm looking for ratings of opening and ending animated sequences (aka OP and ED). Usually an anime has multiple OP and ED sequences for each season and sometimes even more than one of each per season. It would be interesting to compare the ratings with other viewers.

I've seen rating sites for anime characters, character songs, music videos and soundtracks, so I suppose there must be some for OPs and EDs.

Comment: Sorry if I sound like a noob, but I google searched and couldn't quite find out what exactly does OP and ED's stand for.

Comment: It's explained in the first sentence. I'll edit the post for clarity.

Comment: So its Opening and Ending. Sorry about that. Just wasn't sure.

Comment: Wait, clarification - are you asking for sites that have ratings of the songs used for the OPs/EDs? Or are you asking about sites that have ratings of the OPs/EDs themselves (i.e. animation included)? I wrote about the former in my answer, but if you're looking for the latter, I'm not aware of any sites that do that.

Comment: For OPs and EDs. I'm not really interested in the songs alone.

Answer (score 1):

[Gendou's Anime Music](http://www.gendou.com/amusic/) has ratings on the opening and ending songs and offers links to buy the songs.

You commented that you are looking for something for something rating the animation as well as the music, and I don't know of anything like that, but Gendou's Anime Music site is a good reference for finding opening music based on anime title and for rating the songs themselves, so I figured it was worth a mention at least.